# What is :some-parameter in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure and I have seen pieces of code with :some-value. What's that ? I saw some code like this

```
(defn relay [x i]
  (when (:next x)
    (send (:next x) relay i))
  (when (and (zero? i) (:report-queue x))
    (.put (:report-queue x) i))
  x)
```

if I print the when documentation, I don't find :next there

```
(doc when)
-------------------------
clojure.core/when
([test & body])
Macro
  Evaluates test. If logical true, evaluates body in an implicit do.
nil
```

Where is :next definition ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are [keywords](https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Keywords). Googling what they are can be surprisingly difficult if you don't already know what they are.

They evaluate to themselves:

```
user=> :foo ; evaluates to :foo
```

They are unique, potentially namespace-qualified identifiers. Which is why they are frequently used as keys in maps:

```
(def stuff {:a 1
            :b 2})
```

They know how to look themselves up (i.e. you can call them as functions):

```
(:a stuff) ; 1
```

...which is the use-case in your example code. They're quite nice.

Comment: To correct a bit - they're namespace-qualified only if you make them so. The keywords in your answer are not qualified.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov true, I was trying not to go too deep down the rabbit hole. I edited a bit for clarity.